# Codility Cyclic rotation in C#

Tags: c#, algorithm, array

I'm learning C#, I programmed some things in java, and I would like to have a feedback on my C# code. 
The exercise is from `codility`.

> The goal is to rotate array A K times; that is, each element of A will
>   be shifted to the right K times.
>
> Write a function:
>
> class Solution { public int[] solution(int[] A, int K); }
>
> that, given an array A consisting of N integers and an integer K,
>   returns the array A rotated K times.
>
> For example, given
>
> ```
> A = [3, 8, 9, 7, 6]
> K = 3 the function should return [9, 7, 6, 3, 8]. Three rotations were made:
>
> [3, 8, 9, 7, 6] -> [6, 3, 8, 9, 7]
> [6, 3, 8, 9, 7] -> [7, 6, 3, 8, 9]
> [7, 6, 3, 8, 9] -> [9, 7, 6, 3, 8] For another example, given
>
> A = [0, 0, 0]
> K = 1 the function should return [0, 0, 0]
> ```
>
> Given
>
> ```
> A = [1, 2, 3, 4]
> K = 4 the function should return [1, 2, 3, 4]
> ```

And this is my code. It gives 100% but maybe something can be improved.Thanks in advice.

```
using System;
// you can also use other imports, for example:
// using System.Collections.Generic;

// you can write to stdout for debugging purposes, e.g.
// Console.WriteLine("this is a debug message");

class Solution {
    public int[] solution(int[] A, int K) {
        int len = A.Length;
        int[] B = new int[len];
        if(len > 0 && K % len != 0 )
        {
            for ( int i = 0; i < len; i++)
            {
                B[(K + i) % len] = A[i];
            }
        }
        else
        {
            return A;
        }
        return B;
    }
}
```

Comment: Now that I'm looking at it, I believe B could be created inside the if... so if no cyclic rotation is needed computer could save the creation of a potentially large array

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Good Practices

- ✔ I like the fact you don't rotate if the array's length is a multiplication of `K`.
- ✔ As you stated in the comments, the second array `B` gets created too early, since in some occasions it would be created in vain.

#### Review

- The challenge is clearly written for Java:`class Solution { public int[] solution(int[] A, int K); }`. The provided signature deserves its own review (casing conventions, static members, meaningful member names). However, if you 'cannot' change the signature given to you, I would be consistent and use `N` instead of `len` for the array's length.
- You sometimes return the provided array and sometimes create a new one. I would make this very clear in the specification. A consumer should know whether or when a copy is returned. This affects further usage of the object.
- You should guard against the source array being null.
- How would you handle a negative value of `K`? If you think about it, a left rotation is just the inverse of a right rotation.
- Nested statements could have been prevented by inverting the if-statement and exiting early. Less nested statements generally increase readability.
- For bigger arrays you should check [Buffer.BlockCopy](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.buffer.blockcopy?view=netframework-4.8) to optimize copying sections of an array to another array. You could see a rotation as copying 2 sections from one array to another given a pivot. Check out [this article](https://jorgecandeias.github.io/2019/02/23/algorithm-cyclic-rotation-in-csharp/) about the subject.
- If you can change the signature, make a static class with static method, use a meaningful method name `RotateRight` with arguments `array` and `count` and make it clear whether in-place rotation is performed or a new array is created.