# Earliest time frog can jump to the other side of a river in C#

Tags: c#, beginner, programming-challenge, array, combinatorics

I'm new to C#, I programmed a little in Java in the past. I had the two previous exercises reviewed here ([permCheck](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/229525/codilitys-permutation-check-in-c), [cyclicRotation](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/229371/codility-cyclic-rotation-in-c), with a 100% score, just like this one), and I'm applying what the accepted answers contributed to me.

Even though the site expects names like `public int solution(int X, int[] A)`, I refactored the code after it was accepted, and applied those contributions I mentioned.

Is this how professional code should look like in terms of quality, or are there still things to improve in solutions of easy exercises like this written by me?

> ***Task description***
>
> ---
>
> A small frog wants to get to the other side of a river. The frog is
> initially located on one bank of the river (position 0) and wants to
> get to the opposite bank (position X+1). Leaves fall from a tree onto
> the surface of the river.
>
> You are given an array A consisting of N integers representing the
> falling leaves. A[K] represents the position where one leaf falls at
> time K, measured in seconds.
>
> The goal is to find the earliest time when the frog can jump to the
> other side of the river. The frog can cross only when leaves appear at
> every position across the river from 1 to X (that is, we want to find
> the earliest moment when all the positions from 1 to X are covered by
> leaves). You may assume that the speed of the current in the river is
> negligibly small, i.e. the leaves do not change their positions once
> they fall in the river.
>
> For example, you are given integer X = 5 and array A such that:
>
> A[0] = 1
> A[1] = 3
> A[2] = 1
> A[3] = 4
> A[4] = 2
> A[5] = 3  
> A[6] = 5
> A[7] = 4 
> In second 6, a leaf falls into position 5. This is
> the earliest time when leaves appear in every position across the
> river.
>
> Write a function:
>
> class Solution { public int solution(int X, int[] A); }
>
> that, given a non-empty array A consisting of N integers and integer
> X, returns the earliest time when the frog can jump to the other side
> of the river.
>
> If the frog is never able to jump to the other side of the river, the
> function should return −1.
>
> For example, given X = 5 and array A such that:
>
> A[0] = 1
> A[1] = 3   
> A[2] = 1
> A[3] = 4
> A[4] = 2
> A[5] = 3
> A[6] = 5
> A[7] = 4 
> the function should return 6, as explained above.
>
> Write an efficient algorithm for the following assumptions:
>
> N and X are integers within the range [1..100,000]; each element of
> array A is an integer within the range [1..X].

```
/// <summary>
/// Check if a given array contains the integers 1..N
/// </summary>
/// <returns>
/// -1 if <paramref name="fallenLeaves"/> does not contain all integers
///     1..N, where N = <paramref name="requiredAmountOfLeaves"/>
/// a possitive int i, if the required amount of ints were present at 
///     <paramref name="fallenLeaves"/>
/// </returns>

const int FROG_CANT_JUMP_TO_THE_OTHER_SIDE = -1;

public static int GetSecondsRequired
    (int requiredAmountOfLeaves, int[] fallenLeaves)
{
    bool[] leavesAsSteps = new bool[requiredAmountOfLeaves + 1];
    int espectedSum = 0, correctSum = 0;
    for (int i = 1; i <= fallenLeaves.Length; i++)
    {
        if (i <= requiredAmountOfLeaves)
        //get summatory of 1..N
            correctSum += i;
        if (fallenLeaves[i - 1] <= requiredAmountOfLeaves &&
            !leavesAsSteps[fallenLeaves[i - 1]])
        {
        //accumulate where the expected leaf fell and set its location to true
            espectedSum += fallenLeaves[i - 1];
            leavesAsSteps[fallenLeaves[i - 1]] = true;
        }
        if (espectedSum == correctSum && i >= requiredAmountOfLeaves)
        //if all the espected leaves fell, then return the array's 
        //index where the last expected leaf was found
            return i - 1;
    }
    return FROG_CANT_JUMP_TO_THE_OTHER_SIDE;
}
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

### Readability

- The code needs more spacing. Considering the comments, the indentation and the ifs, it's hard to read without some good old empty lines.
- Use brackets when using conditions, especially if you have comments above your single line, it gets really confusing. Also, the readability is increased **and**, the biggest factor, you'll avoid [weird bugs](https://embeddedgurus.com/barr-code/2014/03/apples-gotofail-ssl-security-bug-was-easily-preventable/).
- If you really don't want to use brackets, at least indent your comments so it's clear the line under it is still into the `if`.
- Considering that we have your explanation of the problem, we can understand pretty clearly what your variable names mean. But still... it could be improved or at least well documented. `fallenLeaves` doesn't represent fallen leaves, it represent when leaves are falling at which position. `expectedSum` and `correctSum` don't mean much, to a point I'm wondering if they are well initialized.

**Result for now :**

```
public static int GetSecondsRequired(int requiredAmountOfLeaves, int[] fallenLeaves)
{
    bool[] leavesAsSteps = new bool[requiredAmountOfLeaves + 1];
    int espectedSum = 0, correctSum = 0;

    for (int i = 1; i <= fallenLeaves.Length; i++)
    {
        if (i <= requiredAmountOfLeaves)
        {
            //get summatory of 1..N
            correctSum += i;
        }

        if (fallenLeaves[i - 1] <= requiredAmountOfLeaves &&
            !leavesAsSteps[fallenLeaves[i - 1]])
        {
            //accumulate where the expected leaf fell and set its location to true
            espectedSum += fallenLeaves[i - 1];
            leavesAsSteps[fallenLeaves[i - 1]] = true;
        }
    
        if (espectedSum == correctSum && i >= requiredAmountOfLeaves)
        {
            //if all the espected leaves fell, then return the array's 
            //index where the last expected leaf was found
            return i - 1;
        }
    }

    return FROG_CANT_JUMP_TO_THE_OTHER_SIDE;
}
```

### Algorithm

- You use `i - 1` everywhere but one place, it would be smarter to reverse this. Use `i` everywhere and `i + 1` at one place.
- You use the accessor `fallenLeaves[i]` often, you should consider storing it in a variable. It will make the code more readable. So : `int currentFallenLeaf = fallenLeaves[i];`
- The usage of `expectedSum` and `correctSum` is too complicated for the problem at hand. You don't need to check the sum, only that the number of `true` elements in `leavesAsSteps` (minus one because of the zero index) equals `requiredAmountOfLeaves`.
- You could check right at the beginning of the loop if you already marked the "leaf step" as `true` and that the leaf is valid, so that you don't do useless work.

```
public static int GetSecondsRequired(int requiredAmountOfLeaves, int[] fallenLeaves)
{
    // You should comment why there's a + 1 here.
    bool[] leavesAsSteps = new bool[requiredAmountOfLeaves + 1];
    int numberOfFallenLeaves = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < fallenLeaves.Length; i++)
    {
        int currentFallenLeaf = fallenLeaves[i];

        // Have we already checked this number?
        // Is the leaf number out of range?
        // If so, let's just stop right there for this leaf.
        if (currentFallenLeaf > requiredAmountOfLeaves 
            || leavesAsSteps[currentFallenLeaf])
        {
            continue;
        }

        numberOfFallenLeaves++;
        leavesAsSteps[currentFallenLeaf] = true;        

        // Have we marked all our leaves? We're done.
        if (numberOfFallenLeaves == requiredAmountOfLeaves)
        {
            return i;
        }
    }

    return FROG_CANT_JUMP_TO_THE_OTHER_SIDE;
}
```